# How to include Phaserjs with NWjs

Tags: nw.js

I am trying to use Phaserjs inside NW.js, but it is showing blank screen. While it is working ok in normal browser.
Can anyone help me with it.
Package.json

```
{
"name": "Phaser Drag",
  "main": "phaser/index.html",
  "window": {
    "frame": true,
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got  the answer.

Actually Inside NW.js, phaserjs canvas needs to have *background color* to be given *explicitly*.